# Kernel API docs

Tags: c, linux

Sorry for stupid question in advance, but I'm trying to learn how to write network device drivers and any source I've found so far is outdated and suggest using no longer existing fields of `net_device struct`. I'm might be bad at searching the web, but I wasn't able to find anything useful for couple of days now.

Answer (score 0):

[Kernel docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/) found as the first hit when searching "linux kernel docs".

[`net_device` docs](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/networking/kapi.html?highlight=net_device#c.net_device) found therein (under html/latest) by typing "net_device" in the search box.

Comment: Thanks, I was looking more for some guidance like 'there was ```void (*stop)(void)``` field for ```ifdown ethdev``` handling delegate mentioned in LDD 3rd edition, but since kernel x.x there we use ```module_stop``` or something.

Comment: @jbulatek I don't think anyone bothers to document kernel API changes to that level of detail (if at all), except maybe in the git commit messages.

Comment: What I meant was a course/tutorial/book on linux network device drivers up-to-date with newest kernel

Comment: Recommendations for courses/tutorials/books are explicitly offtopic on StackOverflow, sorry. (Not that I could give you a recommendation anyway...)